# UNMOUNTABLE BOOT VOLUME error on laptop with no CD drive

Tags: boot, unmount

I am getting an `UNMOUNTABLE BOOT VOLUME` error on my Samsung laptop which does not have a CD-ROM drive. I tried to merge the C and D partitions to get more space, but since then the laptop does not start up anymore.

I don't care about the laptop, just about some pictures on there which I did not back up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Linux LiveCD can do. You can download an image and burn to USB then boot it. HDD Partition contents (files) should be present.

Previous partition layout can be restored eventually using partition recovery tools. For example google for "testdisk" - very good tool but some knowledge on disk and partition layout is expected. Do not commit changes with testdisk unless you understand what you are doing.

Comment: The recovery process implemented incorrectly could also destroy all the data, which would be otherwise recoverable. Before running such tools it is **essential** to make a sector-wise image of the HDD!